# How to automatically update each sheet in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm curious to ask if there is a way to automatically update the data that is beeing copied from sheet 1 to sheet 2? like for example if i add a data on sheet 1 it will automatically add in sheet 2?

For example,
I have this one sheet that i'm storing my data:
[image]

Now I can use the data in there by typing the `='<sheet_name>'!<column/row_number>` in the formula, which achieves to update it when ever i changed the values it is connecting to sheet 1, but if i add another row in sheet 1 it doesn't automatically update in sheet 2 unless i clicked the small box icon when selecting a cell.

Is there any way to automatically achieve this so whenever i add a data on my sheet 1 then that data will automatically show in sheet 2?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Elijah, there are multiple ways of doing this automatically.  But if you give extra explanations on what you will do with the data you populate in sheet2, you can have better recommendations.

Comment: Hi @OzgunSenyuva sorry for the late reply, what I'm trying to do is to copy the table from the other sheet, but the problem is that when I add a row from the primary table in which I'm copying the data from, it won't update automatically on my 2nd sheet.

Comment: Sorry but I will repeat myself.  After having all data from sheet1 to sheet2, then what will you do with the data you populate in sheet2 ?  If you just want to make a replica of the sheet1, you can write a simple macro, assign it to a button in sheet1 and whenever you want, you can click button and copy all cells in sheet1 to sheet2 from scratch.  I can suggest something different if this type of a solution will not work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Copying Sheet1 data of A1 to Sheet2 A1

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

Copying in the same file but between different sheets:

```
=Sheet_name!Cell_address
```

Copying in different files and between different sheets:

```
=[Workbook_name]Sheet_name!Cell_address
```

For more visit [Microsoft Page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f).